# How to add keystore and truststore of NiFi registry server to access NiFi registry URL from NiFi server

Tags: ssl-certificate, apache-nifi, keystore, truststore, apache-nifi-registry

I want to deploy NiFi flow from Dev1 to Dev2 and I am using single NiFi registry configured on Dev2.

I have configured NiFi registry URL into Dev1 NiFi server but getting error when it tries to fetch bucket.

```
https://127.0.0.1:8443/nifi-api/flow/registries/8de41f6e-017f-1000-c98d-eca8b48730f2/buckets (source ip: 127.0.0.1)

2022-03-16 12:38:06,260 INFO [NiFi Web Server-22] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication success for admin

2022-03-16 12:38:07,476 WARN [NiFi Web Server-22] o.a.n.w.a.config.NiFiCoreExceptionMapper org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to obtain listing of buckets: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Returning Conflict response.

org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to obtain listing of buckets: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

                at org.apache.nifi.web.dao.impl.FlowRegistryDAO.getBucketsForUser(FlowRegistryDAO.java:80)

                at org.apache.nifi.web.StandardNiFiServiceFacade.getBucketsForUser(StandardNiFiServiceFacade.java:2963)

                at org.apache.nifi.web.StandardNiFiServiceFacade$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$358780e0.invoke(<generated>)

                at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)

                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)

                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)

                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)

                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)

                at org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiServiceFacadeLock.proceedWithReadLock(NiFiServiceFacadeLock.java:161)

                at org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiServiceFacadeLock.getLock(NiFiServiceFacadeLock.java:120)

                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Can someone help how to add keystore/truststore of Dev2 into Dev1 NiFi server to make them communicate.